# Is the 3.5mm jack somehow connected to the phone's transceiver?

Tags: audio, microphone

I could not find a clear answer to that and it's driving me nuts, because I have a microphone, which when connected to my phone via 3.5mm jack picks up a sort of buzz, as if from wireless inteference. Expectedly, the buzzing stops when I put the phone in airplane mode. Also, the mic doesn't pick up anything from other phones or WiFi routers  transmitting.

Curiously enough this buzz is not present when the mic is connected to other phones or a computer.

I have also tried different recording apps... without any improvement.

I figured this could be due to some potentially faulty connection between the phone's audio interface(?) and the transceiver, but am not sure if there is a connection between the two.

Thanks!

Comment: It's more than likely a combination of bad microphone and some kind of ground noise in the phone. There is no *direct* connection between the jack and the transceiver.

Comment: There are a lot of ways for noise to get into a microphone input. They are espcially susceptible because of high gain and high impedance. It may not be due to radiation but to nearfield effects on the circuit board from digital signals. Putting the phone in airplane mode stops the transceivers from transmitting through the antennas, but also probably stops some digital signals on the circuit board. So it is not conclusive proof that the noise is coupling into the microphone input via radiation. It is a solid guess, but not a 100% certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth and WiFi radiate with an antenna.

Clearly the microphone and the cable it has acts as a receiving antenna for the emitted radio waves.

It is possible that the phone and microphone are not entirely compatible for some reason, or that either the phone or microphone is faulty or badly designed.